# How to prefix a sequence # to column names of child 'log' records (for reporting tool)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a parent table `CASES` and child table `UPDATES`. A daily routine logs each row from `CASES` to the `UPDATES` table. This means each `CASE` has one and then multiple `UPDATES`.

**CASES**

```
CaseID  | CaseStatus | [other fields]
=====================================
PK(int) | Free text  | Free text...
```

**UPDATES**

```
UpdateID | UpdateDate   | CaseID  | CaseStatus | [other fields]
===============================================================
PK(int)  | Date Entered | FK(int) | Free text  | Free text...
```

I can use the following query -

```
select *,
  (Row_Number() over (partition by CaseID order by UpdateDate desc)) as SeqNo
from UPDATES order by SeqNo, CaseId
```

to group and sequence the `UPDATES` data into a `#TEMP` table, like -

```
SeqNo | UpdateID | UpdateDate  | CaseID | CaseStatus | [other fields]
====================================================================
1     | 9876     | 30-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
1     | 9875     | 30-Jun-2013 | 789    | [free text...]
2     | 9765     | 29-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
2     | 9764     | 29-Jun-2013 | 789    | [free text...]
3     | 9654     | 28-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
4     | 9653     | 27-Jun-2013 | 345    | [free text...]
```

We use a 3rd-party reporting library. To enable reporting of specific `UPDATES` as sub-components of `CASES`, I need a query that returns data as a flat set of results. In other words, I need to present something like `sq2_CaseStatus` to represent the second-most-recent `UPDATES.CaseStatus` data for any given `CASE` or set of `CASES`. (ie, `CaseId` is/are passed to report code, report code runs my stored procs, my SPs query and return result sets, report code keys on result set columns to find data.)

I only need to present 12 most recent `SeqNo` values (1 - 12) from the `UPDATES` table. But I'm struggling with how to query and return this data within my main reporting query.

**QUESTION:** How to query and return data from `UPDATES` so that `SeqNo` is presented, and available as a prefix for any reporting field?

Apologies in advance if my linear thinking is way of course here...

Within my reporting query, there is a `SELECT` statement that grabs all data from `CASES` and select data from other linked-tables. Within this `SELECT`, could I use a 'looping' technique to call a special function?

This special function would take a counter variable (from 1 to 12), use the variable to query my grouped/sequenced `#TEMP` table by `SeqNo`, and also use the variable to present data back under 'coded' columns. Thus, I'd end up with 12 child tables linked back to my `CASE` records, like -

```
SeqNo | UpdateID | sq1_UpdateDate  | CaseID | sq1_CaseStatus | sq1_[other fields]
=================================================================================
1     | 9876     | 30-Jun-2013     | 345    | [free text...]
1     | 9875     | 30-Jun-2013     | 789    | [free text...]

SeqNo | UpdateID | sq2_UpdateDate  | CaseID | sq2_CaseStatus | sq2_[other fields]
=================================================================================
2     | 9765     | 29-Jun-2013     | 345    | [free text...]
2     | 9764     | 29-Jun-2013     | 789    | [free text...]

and so on...
```

I think this could work. But is it possible to 'loop' in this way within a `SELECT` statement?

*NOTE* - In reality, both the `CASES` and `UPDATES` tables are quite wide, so I abandoned any option of 'widening' my single `#TEMP` table (ie, to present all 1-12 `SeqNo` sets of data for each `CaseId`). Also, I realize that a change to the report interface code could help solve the issue -- but I'm trying to avoid that (costly) option.

**UPDATE / Work-around:** Well, I've had to resort to the single 'wide' `#TEMP` table solution that I originally abandoned. I used a recursive script to help generate my long list of required `MAX` statements -- these produce the prefixed column names. I then combined these with an `INNER JOIN` (performs the sequencing) in a table-valued function. Something like...

```
SELECT up.CaseId AS CaseId,
       MAX(CASE sq.SeqNo WHEN 1 THEN up.UpdateDate ELSE '' END) AS sq1_UpdateDate,
       MAX(CASE sq.SeqNo WHEN 2 THEN up.UpdateDate ELSE '' END) AS sq2_UpdateDate,
       ...
       ...<up to sq12_ for all fields>...
       ...
FROM   UPDATES up
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT UpdateId,
         Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY UpdateDate Desc) AS SeqNo
  FROM   UPDATES ) sq ON sq.UpdateId = up.UpdateId
GROUP BY up.CaseId
```

Comment: which reporting tool you are using?

Comment: To avoid distraction from wanting to achieve this in SQL, I'd rather not say. I will say it's a popular library for ASP.NET apps, allows users to build templates (ie, DOTs, XLTs) and set data output locations using field 'codes' -- these field codes are what I need to generate. So, suppose I want a report to contain general info for each of the `CASES` and also output just their 2nd-most-recent (or 3rd, or 4th, etc.) `UPDATES.CaseStatus` data...  How do I query and return the `UPDATES` data in table form so that it's select-able by `SeqNo`?

Comment: @mjmoody383 the reason why reporting tool is relevant, is because you might be overlooking easier ways to solve your issues. The more relevant information you give the easier it is for someone to help you. Sometimes people are stuck on solving a particular aspect, where changing something else will achieve their goal easier and cleaner.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to return twelve different result sets?

Comment: @zespri A cost would be incurred to change the 'code' (ie, to pass `SeqNo` through the code to my queries), but returning the data as a flat result set from my stored proc would work with current code, thus be free, thus why I'm looking for a SQL solution.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Twelve different result sets linked back to parent `CASES` data -- this would work, as each result set would provide the required unique `SeqNo` prefix for my data columns... it's the only solution my brain has derived thus far (albeit with limited SQL knowledge).

Comment: If your daily routine adds a record to UPDATES for each CASE, can you not simply get the top 12 records ordered by date? That is, can't the sequence be derived from this date?

Comment: Did you look at using `row_number()`  to create the sequence number?

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty... But it should work.

You could use Dynamic Sql within your stored procedure to get a specific child row and construct the names on the fly :

(You might need to change the temp table to a global temp using `##` in order to make this work though)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetChild @chilSeq int
AS
DECLARE @sChild varchar(10)
set @sChild = convert(varchar(10), @childSeq)
DECLARE @dsql varchar(4000)
set @dsql = 'SELECT SeqNo, UpdateID, [sq'+ @sChild +'_UpdateDate], CaseID, [sq'+ @sChild +'_CaseStatus], [sq'+ @sChild +'_[other fields]]
FROM #temp where SeqNo = ' + @sChild

execute @dsql
GO
```

Like I said, it's not pretty, it's not even recommended to use for performance consideration but in your situation that might be the solution you are looking for.